# Google Chrome Extensions - Clicking an icon calls a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I've been trying to make an extension that would have an icon, which upon clicking would stop (all) tabs from loading.

I have this manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "Stop Loading",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Stop loading all tabs in Chrome",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "greyclose.png"
  },
  
  "background_page": "background.html",
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [ "kliknuto.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]
   } ],
   
  "permissions": [ "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]
}
```

In background.html I have this code:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.extension.sendRequest({reqtype: "get-settings"}, function(response) {
    window.setTimeout("window.stop();", 0);
  });
});
```

I'm not sure should I be putting the background.html code into a JavaScript file "kliknuto.js" or something else. Which function is called when you click the extension button in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, background.html is sending a query to itself (`chrome.extension.sendRequest` will not send to content scripts), and then, if/when it gets a reply, the background page is calling `window.stop()` on *itself*, rather than the tabs.  What you really need is:

**background.html**:

```
...
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    // get all tabs in all windows
    chrome.windows.getAll({"populate":true}, function(winArray) {
        for(var i = 0; i < winArray.length; ++i) {
            for(var j = 0; j < winArray[i].tabs.length; ++j) {
                var t = winArray[i].tabs[j];
                // push code to each tab
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(t.id, {"code":"window.stop();", "allFrames":"true"});
            }
        }
    });
});
...
```

This solution uses `executeScript` in place of a content script.

**EDIT with alternate solution:**

Attach a content script to each tab that listens for orders from the backgroud page.

**background.html**:

```
...
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    // get all tabs in all windows
    chrome.windows.getAll({"populate":true}, function(winArray) {
        for(var i = 0; i < winArray.length; ++i) {
            for(var j = 0; j < winArray[i].tabs.length; ++j) {
                var t = winArray[i].tabs[j];
                // push code to each tab
                chrome.tabs.sendRequest(t.id, {"order":"stop"});
            }
        }
    });
});
...
```

**kliknuto.js:**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest(function(request) {
    if(request.order == "stop") {
        window.stop();
    }
});
```

Make sure you add `"run_at":"document_start"` to the `content_script` block in your manifest so that the content script starts listening as soon as possible.

Comment: By the way, my code was missing a parenthesis before. I've fixed it now, so make sure you use the current version.

Comment: I've adjusted the extension now and I got it loaded into Chrome. I reopened Chrome for bunch of tabs to start reloading, but the button of the extension didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Try injecting a `window.alert` and see if that works during and/or after a page load. I have another solution that I'll post shortly that uses content scripts.

Comment: Also, I just realized: `manifest_version: 2` requires separation of HTML files and scripts, so you can't have inline scripts in your `background.html`.  Either change your background page to pure JS (`background.js`) or move your script to another file and load it into `background.html` with a `<script src="..."></script>` tags.

Comment: Additionally, you're using `backgroud_page` in your manifest where I think you want to use `background`.  See [background pages](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html) in the docs.

Comment: Hey Juraj, is your script available somewhere?  Or could you make it available?  I can't stand it when Chrome tries to load all tabs at once on startup...